# Why console.log() does display what i'll push in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, console.log

I don't understand the output of this code :

```
var tab = [];
console.log(tab);
tab.push("Hello");
```

The console will display this :

```
[]
0: "Hello"
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Why does it display "Hello" ?

Can someone explain to me ?

Thanks,

Comment: Have a read here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync

Comment: If you looked at what is actually displayed, you'll see a little `i` beside the expanded list which when hovered over explicitly states: *"Value below was evaluated just now."*. As the marked duplicate states in a couple places `JSON.stringify(tab)` is probably the most useful way to output it if you want it to stay consistent.

Comment: Thank you Nick !